# Possible to stream video from Glass to Hangout web player?

Tags: google-plus, google-mirror-api, google-glass, google-hangouts

I would like to have a webpage plugin that can view the live feed from Glass.  I assume this can only be done through the Hangout API but I haven't messed with it yet.

Is it possible to view a Hangout feed in a plugin on a webpage other than Google's Hangout application?

Answer (score 1):

The Hangout API is mostly intended to run apps inside a Hangout Video Call - not display a hangout as part of an external website.

There is no public way to skin a Hangout Video Call. The closest you can get are some tricks that are part of the Hangout API to track the URL for the Hangout and be able to have visitors to your website join the same hangout. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4 for some details about this, but much of it won't necessarily apply since Glass can't run Hangout apps.

If the Hangout is a Hangout on Air, then you could use the various YouTube APIs to embed the player on a website. But Glass can't create a HoA, although it can join them.